# UPS Error: 250003 Invalid Access License number

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, ups

I am trying to set up UPS shipping API in OpenCart but getting an error of

> 250003 Invalid Access License number

I downloaded the UPS shipping development kit from the official site of UPS. I looked into the forums and find that the issue is with the credentials. I regenerated access key and still getting same error.

I created a controller file and here is my code:

```
    class ControllerSaleUpsShipping extends Controller {
    //Configuration
    private $access = "my_access_key";
    private $userid = "my_account_username";
    private $passwd = "my_account_password";
    private $wsdl = HTTPS_UPS."Ship.wsdl"; // HTTPS_UPS this is the https url to the UPS folder where all schemas file are placed.
    
    private $operation = "ProcessShipment";
    private $endpointurl = 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Ship';
    //private $endpointurl = https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Ship //production URL
    
    private $outputFileName = DIR_UPS."XOLTResult.xml"; // DIR_UPS this is the absolute path to the UPS folder where all schemas file are placed.
    public function index()
    {
        try
        {
            $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $mode = array
            (
                'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
                'trace' => 1,
                'stream_context' => $context
            );

            // initialize soap client
            $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl , $mode);

            //set endpoint url
            $client->__setLocation($this->endpointurl);


            //create soap header
            $usernameToken['Username'] = $this->userid;
            $usernameToken['Password'] = $this->passwd;
            $serviceAccessLicense['AccessLicenseNumber'] = $this->access;
            $upss['UsernameToken'] = $this->usernameToken;
            $upss['ServiceAccessToken'] = $this->serviceAccessLicense;

            $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0','UPSSecurity',$upss);
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

            if(strcmp($this->operation,"ProcessShipment") == 0 )
            {
                //get response
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipment',array($this->processShipment()));
                 //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

                //save soap request and response to file
                echo $this->outputFileName."demo";
                $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName , 'w');
                fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);

            }
            else if (strcmp($this->operation , "ProcessShipConfirm") == 0)
            {
                    //get response
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipConfirm',array($this->processShipConfirm()));

                 //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

                //save soap request and response to file
                $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName , 'w');
                fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);

            }
            else
            {
                $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipeAccept',array($this->processShipAccept()));

                //get status
                echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

            //save soap request and response to file
            $fw = fopen($this->outputFileName ,'w');
            fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
                fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
                fclose($fw);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {
            echo "<pre>";print_r ($ex);echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
    
    public function processShipment()
    {
        $this->load->model('sale/order');
        $order_id = 394;
        $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->getOrder($order_id);
        $products = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderProducts($order_id);
        
        //create soap request
        $requestoption['RequestOption'] = 'nonvalidate';
        $request['Request'] = $requestoption;
        
        $shipment['Description'] = '';
        $counter = 1;
        foreach ($products as $row_product) {
            $shipment['Description'] .= $row_product['name'];
            if($counter != count($products))
            {
                $shipment['Description'] .= ", ";
            }
            $counter = $counter+1;
        }
        $shipper['Name'] = 'name';
        $shipper['AttentionName'] = 'attention name';
        $shipper['TaxIdentificationNumber'] = 'my_tax_number';
        $shipper['ShipperNumber'] = 'my_shipper_number ';
        $address['AddressLine'] = 'my_address';
        $address['City'] = 'my_city';
        $address['StateProvinceCode'] = 'CA';
        $address['PostalCode'] = '90220';
        $address['CountryCode'] = 'US';
        $shipper['Address'] = $address;
        $phone['Number'] = 'my_number';
        $phone['Extension'] = '1';
        $shipper['Phone'] = $phone;
        $shipment['Shipper'] = $shipper;

        $shipto['Name'] = $order_info['shipping_firstname']." ".$order_info['shipping_lastname'];
        $shipto['AttentionName'] = 'Name';
        $addressTo['AddressLine'] = $order_info['shipping_address_1'];
        $addressTo['City'] = $order_info['shipping_city'];
        $addressTo['PostalCode'] = $order_info['shipping_postcode'];
        $addressTo['CountryCode'] = $this->getCountryCode($order_info['shipping_country']);
        $phone2['Number'] = '';
        $shipto['Address'] = $addressTo;
        $shipto['Phone'] = $phone2;
        $shipment['ShipTo'] = $shipto;

        $shipfrom['Name'] = 'my_company_name';
        $shipfrom['AttentionName'] = 'my_AttentionName';
        $addressFrom['AddressLine'] = 'my_Address';
        $addressFrom['City'] = 'my_city';
        $addressFrom['StateProvinceCode'] = 'CA';
        $addressFrom['PostalCode'] = '90220';
        $addressFrom['CountryCode'] = 'US';
        $phone3['Number'] = 'my_number'; 
        $shipfrom['Address'] = $addressFrom;
        $shipfrom['Phone'] = $phone3;
        $shipment['ShipFrom'] = $shipfrom;

        $shipmentcharge['Type'] = '01';
        
        $billshipper['AccountNumber'] = 'my_shipper_number';
        $shipmentcharge['BillShipper'] = $billshipper;
        $paymentinformation['ShipmentCharge'] = $shipmentcharge;
        $shipment['PaymentInformation'] = $paymentinformation;

        $service['Code'] = '08';
        $service['Description'] = 'Expedited';
        $shipment['Service'] = $service;

        $internationalForm['FormType'] = '01';
        $internationalForm['InvoiceNumber'] = $order_id;
        $internationalForm['InvoiceDate'] = date("yyyy").date("mm").date("dd");
        $internationalForm['PurchaseOrderNumber'] = $order_id;
        $internationalForm['TermsOfShipment'] = 'CFR';
        $internationalForm['ReasonForExport'] = 'Sale';
        
        if($order_info['shipping_firstname'] == "")
        {
            $customer_name = $order_info['payment_firstname']." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'];
            $customer_address = $order_info['payment_address_1'];
            $customer_city = $order_info['payment_city'];
            $customer_postcode = $order_info['payment_postcode'];
            $customer_state = $order_info['payment_zone'];
            $customer_country = $order_info['payment_country'];
        }
        else
        {
            $customer_name = $order_info['shipping_firstname']." ".$order_info['shipping_lastname'];
            $customer_address = $order_info['shipping_address_1'];
            $customer_city = $order_info['shipping_city'];
            $customer_postcode = $order_info['shipping_postcode'];
            $customer_state = $order_info['shipping_zone'];
            $customer_country = $order_info['shipping_country'];
        }
        
        $shipto['Name'] = $customer_name;
        $shipto['AttentionName'] = 'name';
        $addressTo['AddressLine'] = $customer_address;
        $addressTo['City'] = $customer_city;
        $addressTo['StateProvinceCode'] = $customer_state;
        $addressTo['PostalCode'] = $customer_postcode;
        $addressTo['CountryCode'] = $this->getCountryCode($customer_country);
        $phone2['Number'] = '';
        $shipto['Address'] = $addressTo;
        $shipto['Phone'] = $phone2;
        $shipment['ShipTo'] = $shipto;
        
        $soldTo['Option'] = '01';
        $soldTo['AttentionName'] = $customer_name;
        $soldTo['Name'] = $customer_name;
        $soldToPhone['Number'] = $order_info['telephone'];
        
        $soldTo['Phone'] = $soldToPhone;
        $soldToAddress['AddressLine'] = $customer_address;
        $soldToAddress['City'] =  $customer_city;
        $soldToAddress['StateProvinceCode'] = $customer_state;
        $soldToAddress['PostalCode'] = $customer_postcode;
        $soldToAddress['CountryCode'] = $this->getCountryCode($customer_country);
        $soldTo['Address'] = $soldToAddress;
        $contact['SoldTo'] = $soldTo;
        $internationalForm['Contacts'] = $contact;
        $product['Description'] = $shipment['Description'];
        $product['OriginCountryCode'] = 'US';
        
        foreach ($products as $row_product) {
            $options = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderOptions($order_id, $row_product['order_product_id']);
            if(count($products) > 1)
            {
                $unitProduct['Number'.$counter] = $row_product['quantity'];
                $unitProduct['Value'.$counter] = $row_product['price'];
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $uom['Code'.$counter] = $option['sku'];
                    $uom['Description'.$counter] = $option['sku'];
                }
            }
            else{
                $unitProduct['Number'] = $row_product['quantity'];
                $unitProduct['Value'] = $row_product['price'];
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $uom['Code'] = $option['sku'];
                    $uom['Description'] = $option['sku'];
                }
            }
            
            $counter = $counter+1;
        }
        $unitProduct['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $uom;
        $product['Unit'] = $unitProduct;
        $productWeight['Weight'] = '3';
        $uomForWeight['Code'] = 'LBS';
        $uomForWeight['Description'] = 'LBS';
        $productWeight['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $uomForWeight;
        $product['ProductWeight'] = $productWeight;
        $internationalForm['Product'] = $product;
        $internationalForm['CurrencyCode'] = 'USD';
        $shpServiceOptions['InternationalForms'] = $internationalForm;
        $shipment['ShipmentServiceOptions'] = $shpServiceOptions;


        $package['Description'] = '';
        $packaging['Code'] = '02';
        $packaging['Description'] = 'Products';
        $package['Packaging'] = $packaging;
        $unit['Code'] = 'IN';
        $unit['Description'] = 'Inches';
        $dimensions['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $unit;
        $dimensions['Length'] = '7';
        $dimensions['Width'] = '5';
        $dimensions['Height'] = '2';
        $package['Dimensions'] = $dimensions;
        $unit2['Code'] = 'LBS';
        $unit2['Description'] = 'Pounds';
        $packageweight['UnitOfMeasurement'] = $unit2;
        $packageweight['Weight'] = '10';
        $package['PackageWeight'] = $packageweight;
        $shipment['Package'] = $package;

        $labelimageformat['Code'] = 'GIF';
        $labelimageformat['Description'] = 'GIF';
        $labelspecification['LabelImageFormat'] = $labelimageformat;
        $labelspecification['HTTPUserAgent'] = 'Mozilla/4.5';
        $shipment['LabelSpecification'] = $labelspecification;
        $request['Shipment'] = $shipment;

        echo "Request.......\n";
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($request);echo "</pre>";
        echo "\n\n";
        return $request;

    }

    function processShipConfirm()
    {

    //create soap request

    }

    function processShipAccept()
    {
    //create soap request
    }
    
    /** Function to get 2 digit country code **/
    function getCountryCode($country)
    {
        $country = ($country == "United States" ? "United States of America" : $country);
        $data = @file_get_contents("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/".$country);
        $result = json_decode($data);
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
        return $result[0]->alpha2Code;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well that never works easily ,

ok try this, make UPS uninstall an then install it again ,this should give you new access key ,now use this new key and see if it works, here are some methods that worked for other developers

(1)"For me it was just the wrong access code, I needed the xml access code.I also had to go back to the UPS site and request an XML Access Key (Code) rather than the HTML Access Key that I first used in the "UPS access code" field for the UPS module.  Now works - or at least displays the UPS shipping options in checkout."

(2)"Mine's solved.  I had to make sure I had the Country, State and Zip User Fields published, required and visible in all locations.  Also, you might want to try making the Registration Method be "Required".  After making that setting, you have to manually make the necessary User Fields be required.  VM's Registration Method doesn't communicate with the User Fields. It's a bug.
"

and if doesn't i would suggest you to contact UPS directly.

Comment: UPS will not offer support on content/syntax level questions. (tried yesterday)